# VS2010 IE renders different

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

So, I have an application that I test on my VS2010 virtual ASP.NET server, when I open it in IE on my local environment, everything renders fine, but whenever I deploy it to the external server, it starts to screw stuff up in IE (CSS and some jQuery problems). I have the same code everywhere, how is it possible to be rendering it differently? (I test them in the same IE version), everything works fine in other browsers.

Comment: I may add that I build my website installer and then install it on the server.

Comment: Do you have compatibility view turned on?

Comment: nope, it is not even available on the pge

Comment: Version(s) of IE and master page declarations might help. Perhaps a code sample via jsFiddle?

Comment: If it's not available on the page, that could mean that compatibility mode was hard-coded in the meta tags.

Comment: I think it is related to compatibility view after all. When I selected display all the websites in the compatibility view, it displayed the same errors. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a compatibility-mode issue. In some cases, IE will jump into compatibility mode unexpectedly. This is often related to browser configuration.

Easiest way to preven this is to add the following meta tag to your HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

This will force IE to always use the best available rendering engine, and prevent it jumping into compatibility mode, regardless of the browser config.

Hope that helps.